# Can you start Ubuntu from a CD or DVD?

Tags: live-cd

I want to get an idea of the look and feel of Ubuntu before committing to installing it on my PC. A number of years ago, I created a CD with Ubuntu that could be started on the PC without permanently installing it. Is that still possible?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0

Comment: You can use a DVD disk (or a USB pendrive) but the iso file (image) is too big for a CD disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, we get an image from the official website, which can be written to CD/DVDs as well.

Asking a question like this here may get you downvotes, buddy.